# Keras Illegal instruction 4 on el capitan

Tags: macos, theano, osx-elcapitan, keras, illegal-instruction

Hi I am using the keras to prototype a neural net classifier. I have used code that successfully ran an another mac machine but when I try to run it on my iMac at work it comes up with the following error message:

"Illegal instruction: 4"

From gleaning on the internet it seems that this might be an issue with theano and the version of mac OS I am using which is 10.11.6 the latest version of El Capitan. Is there an easy way to fix that. I read that you can run the compiler on an older version but I am not quite sure how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: This question is probably better suited for the [keras issue tracker](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues). [This](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3201) seems to include a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3201) in the Keras Github Repository you can solve it by installing Keras freshly from the git repository like

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

or (for the user directory)

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --user
```